# Keep Bootstrap modal hidden once closed

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I have a bootstrap modal that open automatically loading the page (i use it as a popup). When i close the modal, is there a way to keep it closed when i reload the page?

I use bootstrap 4.5

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myModal").modal('show');
});
 </script>
```

html:

```
 <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <p>Some text</p>
          </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: there are many different approaches to this case. one possible solution would be to set a status in the browser storage (have a look at the docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage?retiredLocale=de) if the user already closed the popup and check this status in your js on.ready

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution would be to use a cookie.
Have a event listener for modal hide and set a cookie, when page loads check the cookie if user already seen the modal.

Cookies can be set using `document.cookie = 'key=value; path=/';`.
[More on cookies](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

Edit:
Or localStorage as @SteelNation mentioned in comment.